# destruction of Tripuras mentioned in other samhitas

Tags: shiva, reference-request, yajur-veda, samhita, rudra

The destruction of Tripuras by Lord Rudra is mentioned in Taittiriya samhita as-

> **तेषामसुराणां तिस्त्रः पुर आसन्नयस्मय्यवमाथ रजताथ हरिणी ता देवा जेतुं नाशक्नुवन्ता उपसदैवाजिगीषन्तस्मादाहुर्यश्चैव वेद यश्च नोपसदा वै महापुरं जयन्तीति त इषु समस्कुर्वताग्निमनीकं सोमं शल्यं विष्णुं तेजनं तेऽब्रुवन्क इमामसिष्यतीति रुद्र इत्यब्रुवन्रुद्रो वै क्रुरः सोऽस्यत्विति सोऽब्रवीद्वरंवृणा अहमेव पशूनामधिपतिरसानीति तस्माद्रुद्र पशूनामधिपतिस्ता रुद्रोऽवासृजत्स तिस्त्रः पुरो भित्वैभ्यो.....** [YajurVeda 6.2.3 ]

But is the destruction of Tripuras by Mahadeva mentioned in any other samhita of the Yajurveda?